# php curl: check if a website exists, using textarea input value as url?

Tags: php, html, url, curl

I have a text area box within a form, which let's a user input their company registration number like this:

```
<input type='text' name='creg' id="field_creg">
```

Basically what i want to do is, when a user inputs a registration number into the text area box, i want to use this php curl script which checks to see if a url exists.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/$creg';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (200==$retcode) {
      echo "This is a valid Company Number";
    } else {
       echo "This is NOT a valid Company Number";
    }
    ?>
```

I am using companies house URI which allows you to enter this URL 'http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/' followed by the company number to tell you whether the company exists.

If the company number entered is valid, it will take you to the information page on the companies house website, and tell you about that company, else if it does not exist it will take you to their error 404 page. PHP curl basically checks for this result and if the company number is valid, it will echo "This is a valid Company Number" otherwise it will echo "This is NOT a valid Company Number".

So now i want to find a way of being able to retrieve the text or the value entered into the textarea before the form is even submitted so i can place the value of 'creg'/'$creg' to the end of the url to look like this:

```
http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/$creg
```

so if i entered the company number 12345678 into the textarea box then the url would be

```
http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/12345678
```

however i am trying to get this to check in real time as the user enters the number into the text area before it is even submitted. can this be done?

so the end result is, as a user types in the company reg number into the textarea and it will say whether it is valid or not as they type it.

i would really appreciate it if someone can show me a way of doing this, thanks

Comment: if you use `'` you can not directly use variables. That only works with `"`. Just use `$url = 'http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/'.$creg;`. I bet that is your only problem, but i can't really tell since you didn't mention what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To do 'real time things' you need ajax.

Doing an ajax call is very simple (and crossplatform) using jquery so I'll write code that needs it.

Pretend that `check_valid.php` is the script that validates input and prints if the company number is valid or not.

```
$("#field_creg").keypress(function(){
  value = parseInt($(this).val());
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : "check_valid.php",
    data: { 
      'creg': value, 
    },
    success: function(data){
      // Here data is filled with whatever 'check_valid.php' echoes
      //   Show data
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send $creg via jquery to curl.php  Then you run curl script and get the info of the number is valid or not.

Send creg data click the validation button :

```
$("#checkValidCompanyNumberButton").click(function(){
  var creg = $('#creg').val();
  $.post("curl.php",
  {
    creg: creg
  },
  function(data){
    if(data== 1){
       alert('Valid');
    }
    else{
       alert('Not Valid');
    }
  });
});
```

in curl.php

```
<?php
$creg = $_POST['creg'];
$url = 'http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/$creg';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (200==$retcode) {
      echo 1;
    } else {
       echo 2;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i have tried using this code but it doesn't seem to be working for me, when i type a valid company number into the textarea nothing happens, im guessing it should be echoing out 1 but its not and is echoing out 2

Comment: does my php script need to be in a document called curl.php? as i have tried doing this and also having the php curl code on the same page as my form and jquery and neither seems to work

Comment: Firstly you must include jquery.js to your current page. Then add a button <button type="button">Validate Company number!</button> next to the input. You must write jquery code into <script></script> tags.Then create new php page named curl.php and copy the curl code into it. If you use firefox, you can check console from firebug

Comment: does the jquery need to be in the body of the page or in the header? or before or after the html textarea? if any of that makes a difference

Comment: also is 'var creg = $('#creg').val();' this line of code correct as my html textarea has creg as name and field_creg as id, just check if thats correct <input type='text' name='creg' id="field_creg">

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> add this line to header to include jquery lib. 'var creg = $('#field_creg').val();' is correct. you should change #creg to #field_creg

Comment: does that mean i have to change $creg = $_POST['creg']; to $creg = $_POST['field_creg']; ?

Comment: No. this is correct. You only change the jquery code to 'var creg = $('#field_creg').val();'